# Ant propertyfile task: how can I set an integer with no thousand separators?

Tags: ant

I have a property defined in one of my property files:

`<entry key="build" default="0" type="int" operation="+" value="1" />`

I read this property using:

`<replacefilter token="@build@" property="build_num" />`

Once this number gets bigger than 999, thousand separator commas start appearing, like this:

```
1,001
1,562
```

Is there a way to get rid of those commas?
(I use build to generate a file name, and don't really want to see any commas in there).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can prevent thousand separators from being used by adding a [`pattern`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/propertyfile.html) to the entry:

```
<entry key="build" default="0" type="int" operation="+" value="1" pattern="0" />
```

Note that you'll probably need to manually remove the commas one-time before running this - else your build numbers will reset, with the comma and subsequent digits being discarded. (So **1**,325 -> **2** and **4**,111 -> **5** and so on.)

Answer (score 0):

Figured ###0 would have worked, but it didn't. Since the project is already making extensive use of ant-contrib, it wasn't difficult to add the regex solution Aaron suggested.

```
<propertyregex property="build" input="${build}" regexp="," replace="" global="true" override="true"/>
```